# Losing reference to child object on query

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have 3 Entities (MasterDoc, Folder, User) that i link together in another Entity (Folder_User).

```
public class Folder_User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public MasterDoc MasterDoc { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Folder Folder { get; set; }
}
```

After ive inserted an object of type Folder_User into the database, i can (on the same DbContext) query it and retreive the child objects.

```
public static List<Folder_User> GetAllFolder_USer(User user, DataModel dbContext)
    {
        List<Folder_User> list = null;

        var query = from f in dbContext.Folder_User
                     where f.User.Id == user.Id
                     select f;

        list = new List<Folder_User>(query);
        return list;
    }
```

But after a page-refresh (new dbcontext) when i run the same query the objects reference to MasterDoc is null.

*I have tried turn of lazy loading but nothing seems to fix it.
*Have also checked the database and the table is correctly containing a row with a MasterDoc Id.

Comment: try to use Using(debcontext = new DataModel) each times u call Method

Comment: add ToList() as not sure the impact on dbContext due to LINQ delayed execution.

Comment: That is list = query.ToList<Folder_User>() to trigger the execution as Philip Barnes pointed out since query here is of type IQuerable, it might be due to delayed execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Include` the `MasterDoc` in the query:

```
public static List<Folder_User> GetAllFolder_USer(User user, DataModel dbContext)
{
    var query = dbContext.Folder_User.
                          Include(f => f.MasterDoc).
                          Where(f => f.User.Id == user.Id);

    return query.ToList();
}
```